# Plots Replace Position of previous plot in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am plotting multiple plots on shiny app main panel using checkboxes, Now since my plots happen after checking the checkboxes I want when I uncheck the first check box the second checkbox plot should replace the the poition of first plot  but not to remain fixed on its position. I am using SPLITLAYOUT to plot multiple plots on main panel.

```
         navbarMenu("Data quality Control",
                    tabPanel("Item A"),
                    tabPanel("Item  B")),
         navbarMenu("Tools",
                    tabPanel("Item A"),
                    tabPanel("Item  B")),
         tabPanel("Calibration"),
         tabPanel("Infrared_Prediction"),



         sidebarLayout(

           sidebarPanel(

             fileInput(inputId = "fls", "Choose CSV File", multiple = F, buttonLabel = "Browse", placeholder = "No file loaded", accept = NULL),

             #tags$hr(),
             uiOutput("Raw"),
             uiOutput("SG"),
             #tags$hr(),
             uiOutput("MSC"),
             uiOutput("SNV"),
             uiOutput("SNVDetrend"),
             uiOutput("Baseline")


           ),



           mainPanel(

             fluidRow(
               splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), withSpinner(plotOutput("plts")), withSpinner(plotOutput("plts1"))),
               splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), withSpinner(plotOutput("plts2")), withSpinner(plotOutput("plts3"))),
               splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), withSpinner(plotOutput("plts4")),  withSpinner(plotOutput("plts5")))
             )



           ))
```

))

Comment: Can you provide a complete reproducible example, please? which functionality did you choose to show/hide objects? shinyjs?

Comment: I havent used any functionality to hide and show plots, If you can help me identify such functionality I will appreciate

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example as @Adam has pointed out. Data set with server side and full ui side. Much easier to help that way

Answer (score 0):

Check out the shinyjs package it allows you to show and hide elements with animations that slide them around. Without a reproducible example this is the best I can do for you.